# Toolbar is not visible on MAC OSx

Tags: macos, node-webkit

i have set toolbar true and this is package.json
and i have installed chromium too.

package.json

```
{
"main": "index.html",
"name": "MyApp",
"description": "Example1",
"version": "0.1.0",
"keywords": [ "MyApp", "node-webkit" ],
"window": {
"title": "MyApp",
"toolbar": true,
"frame": true,
"width": 1024,
"height": 800,
"position": "mouse",
"min_width": 400,
"min_height": 200,
"resizable":true
},
"webkit": {
"plugin": true
},
"chromium-args": "--ignore-certificate-errors"
}
```

Comment: Why did you install chromium? What's the current version of node-webkit?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing some of the parameters?

I do get the toolbar by just not specifying anything about it.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "shock",
  "main": "views/index.html",
  "version": "0.7.1",
  "single-instance": true,
  "window": {
    "title": "Shock",
    //"toolbar": false,
    "width": 1150,
    "height": 750,
    "min_width": 950,
    "min_height": 750
  },
  "chromium-args": "--child-clean-exit"
}
```